# how to solve access is denied error in mpi

Tags: mpi

whenever I execute this command

```
mpiexec -hosts 2 machin1(ip address) 1 machin2(ip address) 1 mpiprogram.exe
```

I get this error

```
aborting:Access denied by node 192.16.22.24 
a common cause:this node is a resource managed by the computer cluster scheduler and mpiexec was attempting to use it without the a scheduled job
```

but I don't know what is the problem?what is job scheduler?and  what should I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: that became a little complicated!!!!I just want to run it on two computers which are connected in a local area connection, and I don't know what is job scheduler really!!!but I think  it is not necessary for us to have this job scheduler,the problem is that I don't know how should I uninstall it...where is it?

Comment: Ahh, if you just have two computers connected over a LAN then my earlier comment is off target for you.  That, in turn, suggests that the error message advises you of a common cause, but not of the cause in your situation.  No, a job scheduler is not necessary in your configuration.  But someone knowledgeable about setting up MPI to run on a LAN is.  That's not me.

Comment: Again, you'll need to see my suggestion on your first question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313508/how-to-use-job-submit-in-windows-command). You'll have a much easier time setting up MPI if you use an implementation written for your OS.

Comment: Is there anyone who really MPI.NET on multiple LAN workstations?