# how to use "job submit" in windows command

Tags: mpi

I am programming in MPI over LAN and I have to use the job submit command line, the command is this:

```
job submit /numnodes:2 /workdir:\\%computername%\tests /stdout:pi.txt /stderr:pi.err mpiexec -c 2 PI.exe
```

But when I typed it in command window I will get this error:

> job is not recognized as an internal or external command

So what should I do to run this command in my computer over LAN?

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your tag that you're using MPICH and from your question that you're using Windows HPC Server. While I know nothing about Windows HPC Server, I do know about MPICH, and MPICH doesn't support Windows anymore. You might try using Microsoft's own MPI implementation, [MS-MPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's free to use and will probably integrate with their environment much better.

Comment: NO, I don't use MPICH,I am using "microsoft compute cluster pack SDK" I have installed it, and I am using "mpiexec" and "smpd" in it.but I don't know why I got this error!!!

Comment: Ah. In that case, you'll probably want to contact Microsoft directly. It's possible that some of those users are on SO somewhere, but I've never seen a response from them, so you're much more likely to have some success if you use their support team directly (their contact info is in the link above).

Comment: in fact, I found this packet accidentally , and the name of packet is not important for me!! I just want to install a proper packet which can run an mpi program on LAN, just this!

Comment: MS-MPI is MPICH with added Windows-specific features, among them authenticated remote process launches and encryption.