# mpi packet for c# paralleling program

Tags: c#, mpi

I want to make my C# program in parallel on two host over lan, I know I should use the mpi language, but really I don't know which packet should I install that can connect to another computer, and run a C# program parallel, I just want to run it on two computer,my Os is window7,32 bit operating system,and I am programming with vs2010.

Comment: As I've said in your other questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313508/how-to-use-job-submit-in-windows-command/21314400?noredirect=1#comment32128480_21314400), for MPI on Windows, the only options are MS-MPI (free) and Intel MPI (paid). You're using the correct software, you just have it installed incorrectly. You should contact the Microsoft support team for help with your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use "job submit" in windows command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313508/how-to-use-job-submit-in-windows-command)

Answer (score 0):

You should install something like [MPI.NET](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/) - it provides .NET class wrappers around the MPI API and allows easy use from C#. Be aware though that the C# API is not part of the MPI standard and therefore might (and probably will) differ between different vendors. Unfortunately MPI.NET has been dead for years, probably due to lack of interest in using MPI with C# on behalf of the .NET developers community.

Another option would be to utilise P/Invoke to call the MPI functions from the MS-MPI DLLs directly. This won't work very well due to the differences in the memory models of MPI (especially when it comes to non-blocking operations) and .NET.